# How to get order from particular shop?

Tags: shopware

I'm trying to get orders via api in shopware but I want orders from a particular shop in shopware. does anyone know how to get it ?

Answer (score 2):

Please check [documentation](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/examples/filter/).
You need to use request like:

**YourSiteDomain**/api/orders?filter[*0*][property]=shopId&filter[*0*][expression]==&filter[*0*][value]=**1**

In this case filter will be

```
`shopId`=1
```